# $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin^2x-x^2}{x^2\sin^2x}$

Tags: calculus, limits

$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin^2x-x^2}{x^2\sin^2x}$

I just can't do anything with this besides l'Hospital's rule (which doesn't seem to be a good idea). Can you help me, please?

Comment: Are Taylor series out of the question too?

Comment: L'Hospital is not a good idea? Why not?

Comment: If you use $sin^2x=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}cos2x$ and $cos^2x=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}cos2x$ and use these identities in your limit, L'Hospital will go easier.

Answer (score 2):

Since $x \approx \sin x$ when $x \rightarrow 0$, the denominator is of order $x^4$.

The numerator needs more careful analysis of $\sin x$. Using $\sin x = x - \frac{x^3}{6} + o(x^3)$, we get $\sin^2 x = x^2 - \frac{x^4}{3} + o(x^4)$, so the numerator is $\sin^2 x - x^2 \approx -\frac{x^4}{3}$.

Dividing and ignoring terms of lower order, we get the limit: $-\frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: Looks like a nice solution, but I'm not sure about what $o(x^3)$ is.

Comment: @MátéKadlicskó https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation basically, $o(x^3)$ is something that goes to zero faster then $x^3$, that is some $g(x)$ such that $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{g(x)}{x^3} = 0$. This is standard Peano form of a remainder in Taylor's theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
\begin{equation*}
\frac{\sin ^{2}x-x^{2}}{x^{2}\sin ^{2}x}=\left( \frac{\sin x-x}{x^{3}}%
\right) \left( \frac{\sin x+x}{x}\right) \left( \frac{x}{\sin x}\right) ^{2}
\end{equation*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\left( \frac{\sin x-x}{x^{3}}\right)  &=&-\frac{1}{6} \\
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\left( \frac{\sin x+x}{x}\right)  &=&1+1=2 \\
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\left( \frac{x}{\sin x}\right) ^{2} &=&1^{2}=1.
\end{eqnarray*}